# getting the current time with the google calendar API - Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to get the current time from google with the google calendar api in python?

I built a small desk calendar that shows the current time and my next appointment on a small lcd using a raspberry pi and the google calendar api for python. It works as it should when on my home wifi network, but for some reason my wifi network in the office is not allowing the pi to sync with the ntp server.  I am considering just getting a real time clock module to fix this, but I was wondering if it is possible to just grab the current time from google through the api to avoid this. I can't find anything on this in the reference material for the api.

Comment: That would be weird that Google provide a way to get the time right now. That's not the purpose the the API. You better try to find a ntp server that is not blocked by your office proxy.

Comment: I found out that we have an internal ntp server that I was able to use.  Thanks for the input ffarquet!